# Detect user input using headsets

Tags: iphone, input, avaudiosession, headset

I'm trying to detect user input (a click) on the headphones connected to an iPhone.  So far I've only found how to detect interruptions using AVAudioSession.  Is AVAudioSession right or is there another way? how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want this:

[beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW93)

You implement something this in one of your VCs classes:

```
 // If using a nonmixable audio session category, as this app does, you must activate reception of 
//    remote-control events to allow reactivation of the audio session when running in the background.
//    Also, to receive remote-control events, the app must be eligible to become the first responder.
- (void) viewDidAppear: (BOOL) animated {

    [super viewDidAppear: animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder {

    return YES;
}


    // Respond to remote control events

- (void) remoteControlReceivedWithEvent: (UIEvent *) receivedEvent {

    if (receivedEvent.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {

        switch (receivedEvent.subtype) {

            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
                [self playOrStop: nil];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

See the sample code [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MixerHost/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010210).

Comment: For some reason this isn't working.  I read maybe you have to initialize an AVAudioSession?  Don't really know, I'm trying to make this work but is failing.

Comment: Download the sample code, see if it works for you. Then double check that your VC has those methods I posted. If it isn't in the responder chain it won't get notifications.

Comment: actually the sample code doesn't work either.  I mean, you have to press play in order for the headset buttons to work first.

Comment: I managed to make it work, I did have to start playing some music tho.

Answer (score 1):

It is even easier now, as of iOS 7.  To execute a block when the headphone play/pause button is pressed:

```
    MPRemoteCommandCenter *commandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];

    [commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand addTargetWithHandler:^MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus(MPRemoteCommandEvent * _Nonnull event) {
        NSLog(@"toggle button pressed");
        return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
    }];
```

or, if you prefer to use a method instead of a block:

```
    [commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleButtonAction)];
```

To stop:

```
    [commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand removeTarget:self];
```

or:

```
    [commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand removeTarget:self action:@selector(toggleButtonAction)];
```

You'll need to add this to the includes area of your file:

```
@import MediaPlayer;
```